# Looping through values in a string variable taken from a BizTalk message

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I extract a value from a BizTalk message which looks like this string:

```
UPX:300184-SEQNO:1-401:SHER-410:NONE-450:DEBR-480:NONE
```

I need to look for each occurrence of 'DEBR' which I've done, I then enter a loop for each occurrence and do the following:

Build an account number based on UPX + SEQNO (padded top 3 chars) + the number immediately before the DEBR, in this case 450, so here the account would be 
300184001450.

There may be up to 4 DEBR's, and for each one I have to build a new message and make some service calls.

At the moment I call a C# utility to get the number of DEBR's so I know how many times I need to loop round building the account and doing the call.

My problem is, if there are multiples what is the best way to know which DEBR I've already processed, given that this is a string variable taken from a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try extracting what you need with regular expressions. Start with this:

```
UPX\:(\d+)-SEQNO\:(\d+).+?(\d+):DEBR
```

For example,

```
var match = 
  new Regex(@"UPX\:(\d+)-SEQNO\:(\d+).+?(\d+):DEBR").
    Match("UPX:300184-SEQNO:1-401:SHER-410:NONE-450:DEBR-480:NONE");

var accountNumber = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
  match.Groups[1].Value, 
  match.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(3, '0'), 
  match.Groups[3].Value);
```

Comment: would that be within a Regex.Match()?

Comment: That work well, thanks.  I noticed that it matches on the 1st occurrence.  if I were to include this code in a loop and had more than 1 occurrence in the string, is there a way to ignore the 1st occurrence if it has already been processed?

Comment: @DarkW1nter Care to provide a more real-life example, with multiple `DEBR`s?

Comment: Of course, if the string is: "UPX:308434-SEQNO:2-401:DEBR-410:NONE-450:NONE-480:DEBR", then I would need to build 2 accounts, the 1st your code returned, ending in 401, the next would end in 480.  They cannot be returned as a list as the Biztalk orchestration will call the function once per 'DEBR' if that makes sense?  Thanks for you time here by the way

Comment: After each iteration I am removing the (for example, using your code, 1st iteration ends in 401) 401:DEBR from the string, iterate through again and get 480, remove that, etc.  Not too nice I guess but seems to work for now.  Thanks again

Comment: If I can ask one last thing... can the Regex you provided be amended to match on DEBR or DEBA in the one expression?

Comment: @DarkW1nter That would be `...:DEB(R|A)`